# Sorting data in a reducer in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

**Background**

I am working on my first project using `Redux`. I am trying to sort data in a `reducer`. The `reducer` has 2 sort methods. One for sorting data based on the `timeStamp` and one by the `VoteScore`.

**Problem**

The `reducer` fires off, I can `console.log()` the data and see it is being passed to the correct case when sort is fired off, but the data does not sort on the screen.

**

> I can see when I console.log the data that the data is sorting. So it
>   is just not rerendering.

**

**Example of Data**

```
(2) [{…}, {…}]
{timestamp: 1468479767190, voteScore: -5, …}

{timestamp: 1467166872634, voteScore: 6, …}
```

**Example Reducer**

```
function posts(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SORT_POSTS': {
          switch (action.attribute) {
            case 'BY_TIMESTAMP':
              return state.sort(function(a, b) {
                  return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
              });
            case 'BY_VOTESCORE':
              return state.sort(function(a, b) {
                return a.voteScore - b.voteScore;
              });
            default:
              return state;
          }
        }
        case SET_POSTS:
            return action.posts;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**Example Dispatch & onClick Method**

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.boundSortPosts(this.state.timeStamp)}>Click MeK</button>

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  boundSortPosts: (attribute) => dispatch(sortPosts(attribute))
});
```

**Example Action**

```
export function setPosts(posts) {
    return {
        type: SET_POSTS,
        posts,
    }
}

export function sortPosts(attribute) {
    return {
        type: SORT_POSTS,
        attribute,
    }
}
```

**Initially Rendering Data Like This**

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Posts />
                <div><button onClick={() => this.props.boundSortPosts(this.state.timeStamp)}>Sort by Time Stamp</button></div>
                <div><button onClick={() => this.props.boundSortPosts(this.state.voteScore)}>Sort by Vote Score</button></div>
                {
                    this.props.posts.map((post, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div key={index}>
                                <h4>{post.timestamp}</h4>
                                <h4>{post.voteScore}</h4>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

**Question**

What must I do to cause a rerender at this point?

Comment: Can you post your mapStateToProps()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First and very important thing is you should **not mutate** your state. The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array.You can create a copy of the state array by calling state.slice() before sorting in your reducer, something like this :

```
return state.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
   return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
});
```

Regarding your component not re-rendered, please check your **mapStateToProps**. It should be something like this:

```
function mapStateToProps(state} {
    return {
        posts: state.posts // posts is reducer which is passed to your store.
    }
}
```

Comment: @wuno, has this helped?